# Layer navigation filter not working

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filter

I need to show the layer navigation filter values in above the search page heading.

[image]

> I have tried below code in the
> ***app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalogsearch\result.phtml***
> file.

```
$layout         = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$block_header   = $layout->createBlock('catalog/layer_state')->setTemplate('catalog/layer/state_1.phtml');
$block_links    = $layout->createBlock('core/text_list','catalog.leftnav.state.renderers');
$block_header->setChild('state_renderers',$block_links);
echo $block_header->toHtml();
```

But I am getting empty value.

Please assist me.

Comment: are you using third party extension or creating new one?

Comment: I did not used any third party extension, I have created the custom attributes in backend.

Comment: i think you can get value by `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('your params');`

Comment: Yes its possible, But did not get correct format as per filter showing in left side navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get active filter with below code. tested code..

for category page

```
 <?php 
$_filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

foreach ($_filters as $_filter):?>
<?php echo $this->stripTags($_filter->getLabel()) ?><a href=”<?php echo $_filter->getRemoveUrl() ?>” title=”<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>”><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

for search page

```
    <?php 
 $_filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

foreach ($_filters as $_filter):?>
<?php echo $this->stripTags($_filter->getLabel()) ?><a href=”<?php echo $_filter->getRemoveUrl() ?>” title=”<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>”><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

or you want to show only the current filter state use this code

for category page

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_state')->setTemplate('catalog/layer/state.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

for search result

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/layer')->setTemplate('catal‌​og/layer/state.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: I have printed the array "print_r($_filters);" 
I am getting empty array value.I have filtered two options (rating ,price).

Comment: try it again there was error in code..

Comment: I am did not get error, I have print the array I am getting "  Array () ".

Comment: try this `$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();`

Comment: my bad luck, I am getting empty array.

Comment: updated the code and tested too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33901/discussion-between-vijay-s-and-qaisar-satti).